# server side / client side email validator differences

Tags: jquery, email-validation, expressionengine

I'm using the native jQuery validation library to validate email addresses entered in a contact form. Since this is an Expression Engine site, I'm using its email validator as a server side backup.

When I enter test@b.c, jQuery says it's valid but when submitted, the Expression Engine validator says it is not valid.

I know that validating email addresses can get very complex but which of the two results would you consider as being "correct" ?

Comment: The use case for this conflict is so rare that I wouldn't worry about it at all. If you really wanted to ensure consistency, you can always just use a single server-side validator and have the client validate via AJAX rather than local scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a technically valid email address, but it cannot be delivered to.  (There are no single-character TLDs)
Take your pick.